# Text with `white-space:nowrap` overflows div with limited width

Tags: html, css

Can we make the overflowing text wrap below without a scrollbar and without changing `white-space:nowrap`?

Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoZJaR?editors=110)

Comment: Are you trying to achieve multi-line ellipsis?

Comment: What do you want, exactly?... To achieve the same effect as without `white-space:nowrap`? This is just ridiculous, remove `white-space:nowrap` then.

Comment: Exactly! OP wants to wrap with nowrap

Comment: Any particular reason you'd want to attempt this? If it works, why bother trying to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use `nowrap` when your aim is to wrap? You can add `white-space: normal;`.

Obviously, it achieves nothing more than just removing those `white-space` lines, but as you want to waste some bytes or solve the inexistent problems, go for it.

```css
.outer{
  border:1px solid black;
  display:inline-block;
  max-width:600px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` is needed because without it, text within CSS tooltip gets broken word by word. And with `white-space:nowrap`, the text overflows tooltip area. Please check this link for actual problem: http://codepen.io/cyrilpanicker/pen/BjKzem?editors=110

Answer (score 2):

you can insert `<br>` tags in the text...